# Is there a JDBC package for Postgres on Rasbian / Raspberry Pi, and if so, what's its name or what repository?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, raspberry-pi

In diagnosing a problem, one solution I'd like to try is unavailable to me, and, given what I've seen, I'm curious what I'm missing.

This question is actually, specifically, about, "What does the poor unfortunate one who has got a Raspberry Pi and wants to use JDBC on it to do?" There does not appear to be any "natively available" JDBC driver in the normal Rasperian / Raspberry Pi OS distribution repositories, and in particular not from the OS java library/ies or from the PostgreSQL distribution (which is version 11 - a bit old). If this is true, people without other computing resources are SOL. (Further, and strangely, such drivers brought to Rasperian from other systems don't seem to work - more below.)

But surely, I'm overlooking something?

When I use find on the entire "full" distribution, after installing the latest JDK and PostgreSQL, I come up with a few file / directory entries that include the characters "jdbc", but no drivers:

```
usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libjdbclo.so
usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/jdbcconnectionpage.ui
usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/generalspecialjdbcdetailspage.ui
usr/lib/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/specialjdbcconnectionpage.ui
usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/class-use/JdbcRowSet.html
usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/JdbcRowSet.html
usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/java.sql/java/sql/class-use/JDBCType.html
usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jre-headless/api/java.sql/java/sql/JDBCType.html
```

This is, specifically, from the latest 64 bit version for the new Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. Uname says:

```
Linux <hostname> 5.4.51-v8+ #1333 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 10 16:58:35 BST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

The package manager on this OS says this about the installed PostgreSQL packages:

```
ii  libpq5:arm64                          11.11-0+deb10u1                        arm64        PostgreSQL C client library
ii  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql           1:6.1.5-3+deb10u7                      arm64        PostgreSQL SDBC driver for LibreOffice
ii  postgresql                            11+200+deb10u4                         all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-11                         11.11-0+deb10u1                        arm64        object-relational SQL database, version 11 server
ii  postgresql-client-11                  11.11-0+deb10u1                        arm64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-client-common              200+deb10u4                            all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                     200+deb10u4                            all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

Notably, I asked `apt` to install all `postgresql` packages and captured the output (it's 137 packages long, I think), and there was no entry for `jdbc`, nor for PG Admin, either).

The database on Pi is created, and I can get into it with normal PostgreSQL tools just fine. And, I can get to it through the network, from both PG Admin (a web-based tool) and via other identical instances of the software I want to run on the Pi, just running on a neighboring Fedora box. But the same Java-based software running on Pi won't connect to its own database, nor will it connect to other otherwise identical databases on the local network, which is why  I want to try a native JDBC driver, if possible.

I would get into the JDBC drivers I've actually put on the Pi and tried, and how I declared them to the java program, but that seems a little out of the scope for this question.

Comment: I think we need to see what you have written, and the list of drivers you have used. The drivers for posgres is all here https://mvnrepository.com/open-source/postgresql-drivers

Comment: The postgresql driver from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.19 is a pure java driver, completely agnostic of OS, CPU type and bit size. You won't find a Raspberry Pi specific version of that driver because it is not needed - all you need is a JVM (and that is a requirement for all JDBC drivers...)

Comment: @ThomasKläger That's an answer.

Comment: @aksappy Sure, I can create a new question for that. But first, I want to track down whether it might be related to something I stumbled across in the Pi-port of Postgres in that they seem to restrict connections to "local only" mechanism and not via tcp-ip, which is what, I believe, the JDBC drivers (not just Postgres' driver) expect. It's possible this is the cause, and the drivers I was already using would have worked just fine... I've got some follow-up to do!

Answer (score 3):

The postgresql driver from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.19 is a pure java driver, completely agnostic of OS, CPU type and bit size.

You won't find a Raspberry Pi specific version of that driver because it is not needed - all you need is a JVM (and that is a requirement for all JDBC drivers...)

Regarding PostgreSQL version compatibility: as of today (April 2021), the [About page](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/about/about.html) of the driver states:

> The current version of the driver should be compatible with PostgreSQL 8.2 and higher, and Java 6 (JDBC 4.0), Java 7 (JDBC 4.1), Java 8 (JDBC 4.2) and Java 9.

- The linked driver version 42.2.19 was released in February 2021
- I would expect a driver that is released in 2021 and is compatible with Java 9 to be also compatible with later Java versions.

Comment: Yes, that's a good answer. And, being pure java, that's just the ticket. ... WAY back when these things were first introduced, many such things weren't pure Java, but I guess they all are now. However, the only question now is regarding version compatibility between the older yet current on Pi Postgres 11 and the version 42.2.19 you pointed us to...

Comment: @RichardT I updated the answer with information about Database and Java version compatibility

Comment: @RichardT AFAIK, the PostgreSQL JDBC driver has always been pure Java; at least for the past 20 years.

Comment: The [download page](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) also states: "*If you are using Java 8 or newer then you should use the JDBC 4.2 version*"